# Powershell: How do I continue running script after never-ending script line?

Tags: shell, powershell, process

I have a line in my script that downloads a large video file. After the download starts I want to already open the file while is it downloading. The problem is, is that the download command hasn't finished yet so the script stays stuck on the same line.

```
(Download-File command)

$allFiles = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property name,LastAccessTime | measure-object -Property LastAccessTime -Maximum
$videoFile = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -eq $allFiles.Maximum}
Start-Process $videoFile
```

(I want this to run in a loop while the download-file command is running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy. All you need to do is make it run on a different thread. Use background jobs or Runspaces. Below example is Background Job.

```
$ScriptBlock = {(Download-File command)}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock

do
{
    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property name,LastAccessTime | measure-object -Property LastAccessTime -Maximum
    $videoFile = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -eq $allFiles.Maximum}
    Start-Process $videoFile
}
while (1 -gt 0)
```

Although, I am not sure if you would want to open the video file in a loop. If it does support opening an incomplete video file, you will have just as many instances of it. Better enclose it in an `if (!(Get-Process -name $VideoFile)){}` loop to prevent that.

Comment: Thank you! I am a beginner and that helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the .waitforexit method.

Example:

```
$proc = Start-Process cmd.exe -PassThru
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

After the `$proc.WaitForExit()` line you can open your file.

Its look much better than a loop